# перехват ошибок yii2

Tags: php, yii2, framework, php-frameworks

Хочу отловить все ошибки и уведомлять себя по email о них.
переопределил errorHandler

```
'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ]
```

и уже через site/error проходят ошибки типа 404, но не фатальные.
как сделать так что бы я смог перехватить абсолютно все ошибки, включая db exception и т.д.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Нужно [настроить](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-mailing.html) компонент `mailer` и добавить в конфигурацию `Logger`-а новый `Target`:

```
'components' => [
    'log' => [
         'targets' => [
             [
                 'class' => 'yii\log\EmailTarget',
                 'mailer' => 'mailer',
                 'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
                 'message' => [
                     'from' => ['log@example.com'],
                     'to' => ['developer1@example.com', 'developer2@example.com'],
                     'subject' => 'Log message',
                 ],
             ],
         ],
    ],
],
```

Почитайте про [логирование](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-logging.html), там всё подробно описано.

Comment: Меня интересует именно отлов ошибо даже хотя бы потому что хочу показать пользователю кастомный вид вместо "внутренняя ошибка сервера"

Comment: Тогда внимательно прочитайте http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-handling-errors.html